# action.devices.commands.OpenClose trait in Google Smart Home actions does not work properly

Tags: google-smart-home

When I give command "Open the device 30 percent", the data received by intent fulfillment is

```
{
   "command": "action.devices.commands.OpenClose",
   "params": {
     "followUpToken": "00f38e7b45edbc12fafce49c23568896b7feea58a8a4ba873f31abad7db96de28a25389a2987c7f8deff41afcb25fdffb2b81fe2",
     "openPercent": 100
   }
}
```

As shown above, the "openPercent" is not correctly interpreted. But if I give command "Close the device 70 percent", the data received by intent fulfillment is

```
{
   "command": "action.devices.commands.OpenClose",
   "params": {
     "followUpToken": "00f38e7b4588ad650859efe30a46d7dcb565e3a7eea257919678d5cda32fd769f290298ec8c9d40d0eb3a1b52b0063921823a39d",
     "openPercent": 30
   }
}
```

So we can see that the "openPercent" is correctly interpreted for this command.

Just wondering what caused the action.devices.commands.OpenClose trait only works partially.

Answer (score 0):

- There are two main possibilities of what might be going wrong with the device trait on this one: Your execution might not be interpreted correctly by the Google systems, or your device definition might be in a way such that Google sends you a discrete fully open intent.
- To check if the issue is with the interpretation, you can try typing out the command as well as speaking it via voice, to see if Google sends you different values with the execution intent. Please also try our different grammar, such as “Open the device 30 percent”, “Open the device”, “Set the device to 50 open”, “Partially open the device 60 percent” to see if any of these would help. It might be possible that your intent to open might be always recognized as “100%”.
- The second possibility is that your device definition might lead Google to send you discrete states of fully open & fully close (or one of these, as in your case). To troubleshoot, please check your Sync response for any potential issues on how you define the trait attributes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think the issue is caused by Google NLP. When I give the command "Open the device TO 30 percent", the data can be correctly interpreted. Just wonder why the Google NLP is so unintelligent.